# Connection to IBM Db2 for .net 4.7.2 works but fails after migration to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, db2, connection-string

I can not connect to DB2 after migrating to .net core 3.1.
Previously the connection worked from .net 4.7.2.

Visual studio 2019 professional
DB server runtime client DB2 Runtime-Client Version 11.1.4   -installed
ConnectionString is:

> "Database=hereCorrectName;UID=user;PWD=@pwd@;"

My code looks like this:

```
 using (var con = new DB2Connection(GetConnectionString("IDAA")))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                    )
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                catch (DB2Exception e)

private string GetConnectionString(string db2Infra)
        {
            string connectionString;

            if (db2Infra.Equals("IDAA"))
            {
                connectionString =
                    // ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FoFDb2ContextIDAA"].ConnectionString;

                    BaseConfiguration.Builder["appSettings:ConnectionStrings:FoFDb2ContextIDAA"];
            }
```

Error:

> IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception: 'ERROR [42705] [IBM] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705
> '

Database name is correct, i am using exactly the same connection string for .net framework 4.7 and it works

Comment: in odbcad32 gui, can you connect to that alias?

Comment: On GUI i can Access also can Access with profject which has.net framework 4.7

Comment: The fact that `database name` in the errormessage is followed by empty "" makes me suspect there is something foul with the connection string.

Comment: Are you using the same driver for .Net Framework 4.7.2 and .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: Have you checked that in the new code, the connection string gets resolved correctly from config?

Comment: connection string is exactly the same and resolved correctly from json file i  installed db server runtime client 11.1.4  maybe should be other version?

Comment: ensure the app and project settings are both 64-bit. If you are connecting to Db2-for-Z/OS, either ensure the db2-connect license is applied or your Db2-subsystem has licensing sorted. Please also edit your question to give the version of Visual Studio, and also how you enabled the ibm provider.